# Unsure why I'm getting ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis error. Can't find missing parenthesis

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

Can't find the missing parenthesis or figure out why I'm getting the error.

```
    create table course(
       CourseNum number(10) constraint course_CourseNum_pk primary key,
       courseName varchar2(40),
       startDate date,
       endDate date,
       Ins_ID varchar2(10),
       constraint course_Ins_ID_fk foreign key
        references instructor(Ins_ID)
    );
```

expecting a table with 5 columns to be created.

Comment: Foreign key WHAT?  You are missing the column used for the reference.

Comment: No, @T.S.; both options are correct. Problem was a few centimeters below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
SQL> create table instructor (ins_id varchar2(10) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table course(
  2         CourseNum number(10) constraint course_CourseNum_pk primary key,
  3         courseName varchar2(40),
  4         startDate date,
  5         endDate date,
  6         Ins_ID varchar2(10),
  7         constraint course_Ins_ID_fk foreign key (ins_id)   --> you're missing "(ins_id)" here
  8          references instructor (Ins_ID)
  9      );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Or, alternatively:

```
SQL> create table course(
  2         CourseNum number(10) constraint course_CourseNum_pk primary key,
  3         courseName varchar2(40),
  4         startDate date,
  5         endDate date,
  6         Ins_ID varchar2(10)  constraint course_Ins_ID_fk references instructor (Ins_ID)
  7      );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried creating the instructor table first. Didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for me (as you can see). I can't debug code I don't see. Please, edit your initial message and copy/paste what you did. Do NOT post that as a comment, it'll be unreadable.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I totally overlooked your full line 7 in the first example of code. This fixed my problem, thank you.

Comment: No problem :) You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.